# Distributing TikZ nodes on a grid using the graph command

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, graphs, alignment

I would like the following 10mm nodes to be fitting a 10mm grid using the `graph` command. Instead, the thickness is adding up (I would like TikZ to ignore it).

[image: misaligned nodes]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style = {
    circle,
    very thick,
    inner sep = 0,
    minimum size = 10mm,
    draw = black,
  },
]
\graph[grow right sep=10mm]{
  1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
};
\draw[help lines] (-0.5,-1.5) grid (8,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Am I supposed to size my nodes 10mm − "very thick"??? Sounds a little insane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `outer sep=0pt` to style of nodes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {circle, draw, very thick,
                     inner sep = 0, outer sep=0pt,
                     minimum size = 10mm},
                        ]
\graph[grow right sep=10mm]{
  1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
};
\draw[help lines] (-0.5,-1.5) grid (8,1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: AWESOME! Follow up question: what if I'd like to scale everything (but the text) by 0.75?

Comment: @Atcold, do you try to do this? What was result? Actually, what you like to scale? All except the text? Or only to have smaller text fonts?

Comment: Yes, I did try and it works beautifully! Thanks! I created a separate question since it was too hard for me to explain it here. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/633527/33287

Comment: @Atcold, than see my (correct) answer on scaling problem.